# Are requestAnimationFrame() calls shared between browser tabs/windows?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, createjs, frame-rate, requestanimationframe

I noticed that while I was playing a video on YouTube (in Chrome), an HTML5 game that I'm developing with CreateJS was running half the framerate it usually does.

By itself, on desktop - no problem at running *60fps*.

With the YouTube video running? *30fps!*

Odd thing is, I can't seem to reproduce the issue on a different machine. Could it have something to do with the way different graphic-cards/drivers responds to the **requestAnimationFrame** call?

Comment: Why are you surprised at this? It's one computer with one CPU. It can only do so much at one time.

Comment: That's like saying "well, my operating system will run program A 50% slower if I run program B at the same time." We live in modern days of multithreading CPU cycles, multi-core. So no, I don't think RAF is asking it to do too much at one time :P

Comment: I don't even know what "multithreading CPU cycles" means. Multithreading means the machine has infinite resources? A program will indeed run slower if the machine is heavily loaded, all else being equal.

Comment: So you're saying that because one video playing in YouTube in one window, my RAF calls in the other browser window **halves** because my 12-core CPU is *struggling* to keep running at 60fps?

Comment: In and of itself, RAF is quite lightweight. It simply manages a queue of requests and invokes them when it gets the chance. So the only logical explanation is that in fact the browser/tab is getting fewer cycles and reaching the point in its processing pipeline to to invoke the queued-up RAF function less often. Other than that, it's hard to say, especially since as you say the problem is not reproducible on other machines.

Answer (score 1):

No. Different browser tabs do not share RAF calls.

If you have 2 browser tabs each with an RAF loop, the tab that is focused will run its RAF loop and the tab that is not focused will have its RAF stopped.

However, if you have multiple RAF calls on a single browser tab, all those RAF calls will be merged into a single execution which is synchronized with the display refresh.

Comment: what if the tabs are in separate windows (side-by-side)? Will they both run at their full framerate?

Comment: If the tabs are in separate instances of the browser, then the animations will continue.

Comment: Alright. Well thanks for the insight on RAF. Unfortunately I still don't understand how the two tabs I was running separately was causing a framerate drop in the HTML5 game. I think I'll just delete this question and rephrase it in another.

Answer (score 1):

RequestAnimationFrame is not something that works at the graphic card or driver level. It's a browser-specific software concept, where the browser can be asked to call the program to do some rendering tasks at times which are optimized based on where the browser is in its processing pipeline, and at a higher precision than older alternatives such as `setTimeout`.

As @markE correctly notes, RAF pauses when a tab is not active, so there is no performance issue related to RAFs going on in multiple tabs. Indeed, the ability to pause RAF-based animations in inactive tabs was one of the motivations for introducing it.

However, YouTube does not use RAF. As far as I know, YouTube videos continue running in background tabs. The graphics subsystem does much of the work, but the CPU is involved too; the pixels have to brought in from somewhere and fed to the graphics system. On a multi-core CPU, a new process might in theory be able to use an underutilized core, but at the end of the day CPU resources are finite. The more work it has to do, the more everything slows down, and in particular the less resources it can devote to the browser or to a particular thread running a browser tab. So yes, it is not at all surprising that you would see such a slowdown.

Comment: Great answer! Is it possible to enable RAF when a tab is not active though?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, that is a browser implementation issue.